# How do I create a new server side view with Treeline?

Tags: sails.js, treeline

I'm building my first app with Treeline, and I'd like to create a new server side view. Using Sails, I'd normally add the route and associated view to config/routes.js, but when I link my Treeline project config/routes.js is overwritten by the routes defined in Treeline.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To serve a view in Treeline, you should change the response type- this will result in a separate response being used in the compiled code:

[image: screenshot of changing response]

First click "respond", then "display view".  After that, enter the name of the view and provide any locals you need access to (this is equivalent to `res.view` in Sails, or `res.render` in Express)